# Accessing an instance method in an active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given the following two models:

```
class Wheel
  belongs_to :car

  def self.flat
    where(flat: true)
  end
```

and

```
class Car
  has_many :wheels

  def flats
    self.wheels.flat
  end

  def has_flats?
    flats.count > 0
  end
```

I need a query for all cars with flat tires. I'm wondering why this isn't working in the cars model?:

```
def self.with_flats
  where(:has_flats?)
end
```

or

```
def self.with_flats
  where(:has_flats? == true)
end
```

This isn't returning the correct records. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Define a scope in Car model:

```
class Car
  has_many :wheels

  scope :having_flat_wheels, joins(:wheels).where("wheels.flat=?", true).uniq
  ......
end
```

Then to get all cars with flat tires:

```
Car.having_flat_wheels
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - Unfortunately I think this returns a car for every flat wheel, so if a car has 4 flat tires, it will be added 4 times to an array. I'm just looking for a collection of cars with flat tires.

Comment: BTW I prefer using instance methods to scopes, so:

def having_flat_wheels
  where("wheels.flat=?", true).joins(:wheels)
end

I just can't seem to figure out how to use the car model's has_flats? method in the where clause like this:

def self.with_flats
  where(:has_flats?)
end

Comment: @psrabbit: So you want to say that car having multiple flat wheels appear more than once and you want unique cars.

Comment: instance methods are for particular instance only. You can use them for some specific car record but not for the class.

Comment: You should try: scope :having_flat_wheels, joins(:wheels).where("wheels.flat=?", true).uniq